# Setup subdomains in docker environment

Tags: nginx, docker, subdomain

I am running different services in Docker Containers on my Ubuntu server (14.04 Trusty Tahr) at home. My currently Setup at the moment is as following:

- Jenkins jenkins.slarti
- Gitlab and leanlabs.io under gitlab.slarti
- Java Servlet Webserver under servlet.slarti (apache tomcat)
- "Normal" Webserver under web.slarti (nginx)

These domains are virtualhost's and I have already setup an nginx proxy.

Nginx-proxy docker run:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Jenkins docker run:

```
docker run -d --name jenkinsci --expose 8080 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=jenkins.slarti -e VIRTUAL_PORT=8080 jenkins
```

Normal Webserver docker run:

```
sudo docker run --name nginx1 -P -d --expose 80 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=web.slarti nginx
```

Gitlab & leanlabs.io docker run:

```
docker run -d  --link kanban_redis:kanban_redis -p 80:80 -e KANBAN_SERVER_HOSTNAME="http://localhost"  -e KANBAN_GITLAB_URL="http://mygitlab.com"  -e  KANBAN_REDIS_ADDR="kanban_redis:6379" --expose 80 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=gitlab.slarti leanlabs/kanban:1.4.0
```

Apache Tomcat docker run:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8090 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=servlet.slarti tomcat:8.0
```

I did the setup according to this guide [http://blog.florianlopes.io/host-multiple-websites-on-single-host-docker](http://blog.florianlopes.io/host-multiple-websites-on-single-host-docker/)

Currently I can't ping web.slarti, servlet.slarti etc. Neither can i reach these domains if i type their url in the browser.

I can reach Apache Tomcat via slarti:8888 but I want to reach it through servlet.slarti and that fails since i don't have a DNS setup.

What do I have to do to reach the subdomains web.slarti, servlet.slarti etc? How do I setup the reverse proxy correctly so I can reach the domains? And how do I have to configure the DNS?

Comment: I really can't figure out what is the problem, nor the question, nor what you _did_ try.

Comment: Can you ping their IP address? If yes, you have no DNS resolving.

Comment: I can ping the ip's of the container on a client but there is always a total loss of packets.

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert on networks. But after reading your post, it appears that you do need a DNS config like this:

```
A -> slarti (or IP)
CNAME jenkins.slarti -> slarti
CNAME gitlab.slarti -> slarti
CNAME servlet.slarti -> slarti
CNAME web.slarti -> slarti
```

This is what I have done to redirect my subdomains to my Docker containers.

Without proper DNS configuration, your subdomains can't be reached.

With this DNS config, everytime you request *gitlab.slarti*, you actually reach Nginx, which in turn redirects you to the proper Docker container (if the ***VIRTUAL_HOST*** environment variable is configured to *gitlab.slarti*).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an A record for `*.example.com` for the root IP Address of the machine (Your Ubuntu Server).
2. Then start binding as much sub domains you want to bind with multiple docker containers those are running different services.

For example:

```
docker run -d --name jenkinsci --expose 8080 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=jenkins.slarti -e VIRTUAL_PORT=8080 jenkins
```