# Setting-up containers reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, docker

I try to set up a reverse proxy in front of multiple containers including gitlab using nginx. Basically, when trying to access mydomain.com/gitlab, I want to be forwarded to mydomain.com:7777

Both servers are running over their own containers and both are up and running.
However, no request is forwarded to gitlab.

Here my config.d file for nginx.

```
 upstream gitlab {
  server                    mydomain.com:7777 fail_timeout=0;
 }

 # let gitlab deal with the redirection
 server {
  listen                    *:80;
  server_name               mydomain.com;
  server_tokens             off;
  root                      /dev/null;

  # Increase this if you want to upload larger attachments
  client_max_body_size      20m;

  # individual nginx logs for this vhost
  access_log                /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log                 /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location /gitlab/ {
    proxy_set_header        Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass              http://gitlab;
  }
 }
```

I have tried replacing the domain.com address with internal docker ips w/o any success.

Comment: Containers on same network or linked?

Comment: Thanks for your support. Containers are on the same network and by using container ip address and port (docker inspect), gitlab is now accessible. By the way, gitlab redirects to http://example.com/users/sign_in instead of http://example.com/gitlab/users/sign (I have set http://example.com/gitlab as external url in gitlab.rb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Automated Nginx reverse proxy for docker containers

> nginx-proxy sets up a container running nginx and docker-gen.
>   docker-gen generates reverse proxy configs for nginx and reloads nginx
>   when containers are started and stopped.

Comment: Well, at this stage, I would like to avoid the usage of additional containers.

Comment: Thanks for your support, i could finally solve the issue with nginx-proxy and some network modifications as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149196/setup-subdomains-in-docker-enviroment